# Can you compose css classes within :local and :global selectors together?

Tags: css, css-modules

Our codebase uses CSS Modules (wrapped by a typescript library -- `typings-for-css-modules-loader`).

I'm wondering if it's at all possible to use class composition when having a combination of :global and :local selectors:

```
:global .mobile-view :local .my-specific-dev {
  composes: narrow-width from global;
}
```

The error message is pretty explicit, `Error: composition is only allowed when selector is single local class name`. I'm wondering if there is another way to achieve this, or some additional config to enable. It seems like a pretty common use-case when using CSS Modules to not be supported.

Thanks!